# How does the FIRST_VALUE() function in Oracle process rows if there is no order by clause?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, data-warehouse, analytic-functions

First_value() definition states that it returns the first value in an ordered data set. It's syntax is

First_Value(ColumnName) over ( [Partition By Colum] [Order by Column] )

The Partition By and Order By are optional. If partition by is removed, we get first value of whole set.

**My question is what do we get if Order By is removed ??
Does oracle implicitly orders the set or just gives a random first value or gives the first value in order the data is inserted ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realistically, if you don't specify an `ORDER BY`, you'll get the data in the order that Oracle returns the result set.  That's going to be arbitrary and subject to change as the query plan changes.